# WebSphere Server V.8.5 troubles with Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, websphere

### I'm trying to create an IBM WebSphere V.8.5 web app using Eclipse.

I downloaded and installed all the IBM packages needed and followed [the official guide to create server and project](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/jaxrpc/twasserv.htm).
Then I created an index.jsp under WebContent folder with just some HTML/CSS tags to print a static "Hello world".
Visiting `http://localhost:9080/project_name/index.jsp` I get the following:

> Error message: JSPG0036E: Unable to find resource
>   /project_name/index.jsp

I've already search for the error but ant solution was valid for my case.
The error continues...

> Root cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Unable to find
>   resource /project_name/index.jsp  at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:447)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1010)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3980)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>
> ...

Comment: You're probably going to find your answer [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21282614).

Comment: Following suggested path `install_root\profiles\profile_name\installedApps<CELL>\<EAR>\<WAR>` there isn't any `<EAR>` folder called `project_name.ear`. So it should mean it's not developed in the webserver, but I'm launching the server of the project using Eclipse, I thought it would automatically deploy the EAR/WAR.

Comment: when you add the EAR/WAR file to the server using the integrated tools, it should spit out a URL which you can then use to subsequently navigate to the webapp.  in your EAR you can specify the context root.

Comment: Ok, I manually added the .WAR file in WebSphere server as Enterprise Application and it didn't work, so I tried with the .EAR and it starts without any error.
@PaulBastide I'm not familiar with WebSphere and right now I'm unable to find the right URL to visit. I tried following what Mena's link say but still nothing. Any suggestion on where to find the URL?

Comment: Ok, got it!
`http://hostname:9080/project_name/index.jsp`

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse doesn't provide an automatic build and launch of the web project so you have to export an EAR file (not WAR!) and import it into WebSphere Control Panel as WebSphere Enterprise Application.
Then just leave the options as they are and click "next" as many time as needed; in the WebSphere Enterprise Application panel you have to select the app just added and click "Launch"; it should work and then you can visit the URL `http://hostname:9080/project_name/your_page.jsp`.

Comment: That is totally incorrect. If you install WebSphere Developer Tools to your Eclipse and add WebSphere Server to your Servers view, you just click the server and select `Add and Remove..` to add project there. There is absolutely no need to export and install it separately.

Comment: I added the project's EAR to the server but if I start it, it doesn't unpack and run the project. If it does, I don't know how to reach the correct URL because the one indicated in IBM's website doesn't work. Please tell me if you know how to get it @Gas

Comment: Just right click your jsp page and select `Run As > Run on Server'. Internal browser should be opened with your page.